# My Insert Into Statement is not working

Tags: java, sql, database, jdbc

I was working with UIs where the user will click the add button to add employees, but when I do it, it gives me an error like this

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`finalpayroll`.`personal_info`, CONSTRAINT `personal_info_ibfk_1`
```

How would I fix this?? I know I am using a parent key, and its foreign key is the User, and also take note that the parent key has already a data, but it seems my query won't work, why is that?  I am using a foreign key with delete cascade and on update cascade so that when I delete a data, all of the child table rows will be deleted, vice versa. here's my key for adding or inserting statements

```
public void addEmployee(Personal p ,Contact c,Employee e) {
    Connection conn = Jdbc.dbConn();
    Statement statement = null;
    String insert1 = "INSERT INTO personal_info (`First_Name`, `Middle_Initial`, `Last_Name`, `Date_Of_Birth`, `Marital_Status`, `Beneficiaries`) VALUES ('"+p.getFirstName()+"', '"+p.getMiddleInitial()+"'" +
                "       , '"+p.getLastName()+"', '"+p.getDateOfBirth()+"', '"+p.getMaritalStatus()+"', '"+p.getBeneficiaries()+"')";
    try {
        statement = conn.createStatement();
        statement.executeUpdate(insert1);
        statement.close();
        conn.close();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Employee Added!!");
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Users table:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `idusers` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `emp_id` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `emp_pass` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idusers`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Personal_info table:

```
CREATE TABLE `personal_info` (
    `idpersonal_info` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `First_Name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    `Middle_Initial` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    `Last_Name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    `Date_Of_Birth` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    `Marital_Status` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    `Beneficiaries` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`idpersonal_info`),
    CONSTRAINT `personal_info_ibfk_1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idpersonal_info`)
    REFERENCES `users` (`idusers`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: can you share table create statements for both user and personal_info?  Which field in personal_info table refer to User table? You're not setting any id-like field in your query..

Comment: It say personal_info_ibfk_1 is violated.   Have you looked at that constrainst?

Comment: It would be good if you could post the schema to the table. It will let people give you more accurate advice.

Comment: You have to be careful with appending parameters as String to the SQL statement because you are prone to SQL injection. Use PreparedStatement set* methods.

Comment: @Alfredo, can you show me how to do that here???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to insert a record with 6 fields: `First_Name`, `Middle_Initial`, `Last_Name`, `Date_Of_Birth`, `Marital_Status` and `Beneficiaries`. Your schema is currently unknown but none of these fields seem to be a candidate foreign key to id of `User` table you mentioned. Thus I think there is a default value for that foreign key column and that default value is missing in User table.

Needless to say, you shouldn't have a default value for a foreign key of any table..

I am adding these information regarding your questions in comments and update on your question:

A foreign key is a link between a child table and parent table, `personal_info` and `users` tables in your case respectively. Child table's foreign key column must reference to a key value in parent table which means that for every value in child table's FK column, there must be a value in parent table's linked column.

Now, in your case when you try to insert a new personal_info record MySQL assigns a `idpersonal_info` to it, since you defined it as auto increment. But since there is a link to users table, MySQL searchs for the new `idpersonal_info` to be inserted in users table's `idusers` column. And as you are getting this exception, you surely don't have that value in the users table.

You can change your table structure as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `personal_info` (
  `idpersonal_info` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,

  ... OTHER FIELD DEFINITIONS,

  PRIMARY KEY (`idpersonal_info`),
  CONSTRAINT `user_id_fk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`idusers`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

And your query will need to include `user_id` field as well. So it will be something like this:

```
INSERT INTO personal_info
  (`user_id`, `First_Name`, `Middle_Initial`, `Last_Name`, `Date_Of_Birth`, `Marital_Status`, `Beneficiaries`)
VALUES ( .... SET YOUR VALUES HERE. DON'T FORGET TO SET A VALID USER_ID
```

Comment: but I thought, I set the Table for auto increment??? , so I was thinking I don't need to insert the primary key here, or the primary ID here

Comment: I was thinking that, if I insert these values into to this table it will have an automated value since I set it as an auto increment, and I do have entries on my user table

Comment: Can you run `show create table User` and `show create table personal_info` and add output of both query to your question as an edit?

Comment: I updated my question, I posted the Users and the table personal info.

Comment: I am updating the answer to reflect your table structure

Comment: Then how would I, get the last auto incremented value, and then set it as a value to another table?? for example, the primary id of Users table is 1, how could I make that as my primary key to to other tables??

Comment: how would get the last autoincremented value from another table or parent table then set it as a key/primary key for another table???

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5729/discussion-between-melihcelik-and-kyeljmd)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like in your Personal_Info table you have a column called "finalpayroll", that points to a column in another table (a foreign key) and it's required (not nullable). In your insert you're not giving it a value. So what you could do is make that column nullable.

Or could be the other way around as @Konstantin Naryshkin is saying

Comment: but this table has an auto increment,I was thinking it would do the job

Answer (score 0):

What the error means is that you are trying to insert a value into a column with a foreign key a value that is not in the remote table.

I assume that there is a user column that we are not seeing. Since you are not explicitly setting the value, I assume that it is getting a default. The default value is not in the parent table.

Comment: But ,It's on auto increment, I was thinking it would automatedly  set its value to 1 or depending on the last value?